Adjust fraction parts to arrive to specific rate
Let say the target rate is: 0.2312076819339227309219662514224185
How to adjust this fraction 984398920/4257639330 that gives this rate: 0.23120768193392275902336706383252993860332457986759 (matches the 16th number after the floating point) to match the 18th number after the floating point?
The final fraction is: 939515904/4063515088
Also the fraction parts should not exceed 0xffffffff (4200000000)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you know about continued fractions, Ben?

Yeah, the initial fraction obtained using continued fractions, but it does not gives accurate result within the interval

I think the best you can do with denominator at most $4200000000$ is $715427443/3094306543=0.23120768193392274$.

I already submit the final fraction, but I don't know the way to arrive to it, even I subtract 1000000 for each loop the rate the accuracy will reduced to 10th number, exemple 939398920/4061234567

Are you saying $939515904/4063515088$ is better than $715427443/3094306543$?

@GerryMyerson I don't know what does that fraction gives (715.../309...)

https://www.calculator.net/big-number-calculator.html gives $0.23120768193392273093$ to 20 decimals.

@GerryMyerson yes, it matches the 19th numbers, how did you found it?

I found a website that turned the decimal into a continued fraction, and that calculated the convergents to that continued fraction, and I chose the last convergent that gave a denominator less than your bound.

If you want it to match the 16th number after the floating point you can simply do
$$2312076819339227/10000000000000000$$
It will be '7' in the 16th digit, just like your target number.

It should be obvious how to extend this solution to an arbitrary degree. More 0's on the denominator and more numbers from the decimal in the numerator. Cheers.

I forget to add the limits, fraction parts should not exceed 0xffffffff (4200000000)
